# symfony in a home directory on debian with apache & userdir.conf

Tags: symfony, public-html

After installing symfony in a user's directory (/home/user/public_html/my-project), the web directory does not appear by querying http://nameserver.com/~user/my-project and the following apache error appears by querying http://nameserver.com/~user/my-project/web : **Internal Server Error**

If the installation is done in /var/www/html/my-project, everything works well. However, I have to install it in the user's directory :(

Should I change/adapt the web/.htaccess if symfony is in /home/user/public_html ?

Server is a debian with apache 2.4.25

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf :

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
    UserDir disabled root

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
        Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
        Require method GET POST OPTIONS
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

error.log apache2:

AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/user/public_html/symfony/src/, referer: https://nameserver.com/~user/

/home/user/public_html/symfony/web/.htaccess: Options not allowed here, referer: https://nameserver.com/~user/

AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/user/public_html/symfony/app/, referer: https://nameserver.com/~user/

Symfony :

```
-------------------- ------------------------------------------- 
  Symfony                                                         
 -------------------- ------------------------------------------- 
  Version              3.4.8                                      
  End of maintenance   11/2020                                    
  End of life          11/2021                                    
 -------------------- ------------------------------------------- 
  Kernel                                                          
 -------------------- ------------------------------------------- 
  Type                 AppKernel                                  
  Name                 app                                        
  Environment          dev                                        
  Debug                true                                       
  Charset              UTF-8                                      
  Root directory       ./app                                      
  Cache directory      ./var/cache/dev (773 KiB)                  
  Log directory        ./var/logs (41 KiB)                        
 -------------------- ------------------------------------------- 
  PHP                                                             
 -------------------- ------------------------------------------- 
  Version              7.0.27-0+deb9u1                            
  Architecture         64 bits                                    
  Intl locale          n/a                                        
  Timezone             Europe/Berlin (2018-04-24T16:37:05+02:00)  
  OPcache              true                                       
  APCu                 false                                      
  Xdebug               false                                      
 -------------------- -------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably Symfony .htaccess tries to change some settings that is not allowed by your configuration. At first I suggest change line: `AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes` into `AllowOverride all`. Or if you can't do this for security reasons, look into symfony .htaccess, and try to change tihs `AllowOverride` directives list to work with this used in symfony .htacces.

Comment: By making this change, the directory is actually accessible but I have this error if I query it :  "loadClassCache(); } //$kernel = new AppCache($kernel); // When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter //Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride(); $request = Request::createFromGlobals(); $response = $kernel->handle($request); $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

Comment: unfortunately, I have no more information about this error except this message.